# Netsuite record.save in Suitescript2.0 is returning 200OK but not creating a record (but the same works with SuiteScript1.0)

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, invoice, suitescript2.0

I created a restlet script that is meant to post data into Netsuite to create an invoice record, and return the recordID.
The data is being sent from Postman in JSON format.

When I tried it with Suitescript 1.0, it was able to create the record, however when I tried the same logic with Suitescript 2.0, it doesn't work.

The Suitescript 1.0 script did the following upon first request:

- returned 200 OK and the record ID of the newly created record

The Suitescript 2.0 script did the following:

- initially returns error 400: bad request
- upon sending once more, returns status 200OK but no record ID is returned
- when I check the Netsuite UI, no invoice record is created

This is the suitescript 1.0 code (which I found on the internet):

```js
function createRecord(datain)
{
    var err = new Object();
    var record = nlapiCreateRecord('invoice');
    for (var fieldname in datain)
    {
   if (datain.hasOwnProperty(fieldname))
   {
    if (fieldname != 'recordtype' && fieldname != 'id')
    {
     var value = datain[fieldname];
    if (value && typeof value != 'object') // process non-item fields
     {
      record.setFieldValue(fieldname, value);
     }
     if (value && typeof value == 'object') // process line item objects
     {
      for (var itemobject in value)
      {
       record.selectNewLineItem('item');
       var lineitemobject= value[itemobject];
       for (var lineitemfieldname in lineitemobject )
       {          
        var lineitemfieldvalue = lineitemobject[lineitemfieldname];
        record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item',lineitemfieldname,lineitemfieldvalue);      
       }
       record.commitLineItem('item');                            
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }

    var recordId = nlapiSubmitRecord(record);
    return recordId;
}
```

This is my suitescript 2.0 code:

```js
// Create a NetSuite invoice
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType Restlet
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

//define and declare modules
define(['N/record'], function(record)
{
//function to create a new invoice record with data from API

function createInvoice(datain)
{
    //create record
    var record = record.create({
        type: record.Type.INVOICE,
        isDynamic: false, 
        defaultValues: null
    });

    for (var fieldname in datain)
    {
        if (datain.hasOwnProperty(fieldname))
        {
        if (fieldname!='recordtype' && fieldname!='id')
        {
            var value = datain[fieldname];

            // process non-item fields
            if (value && typeof value != 'object')
            {
                record.setValue({
                fieldId: fieldname,
                value: value
                });
            }   //close non-item field processing if stmt

            // process line item sublist objects
            if (value && typeof value == 'object')
            {
                for (var itemobject in value)
                {
                    record.selectNewLine({sublistId:'item'});   //selects a new line at the end of a sublist
                    var lineitemobject= value[itemobject];
                    for (var lineitemfieldname in lineitemobject)
                    {
                        var lineitemfieldvalue = lineitemobject[lineitemfieldname];
                        record.setCurrentSublistValue({
                            sublistId: 'item',
                            fieldId: lineitemfieldname,
                            value: lineitemfieldvalue
                        });
                    }   //close lineitemobject for loop
                    record.commitLine({sublistId: 'item'});//Commits the currently selected line on a sublist --> dynamic mode only
                }   //close value for loop
            }   //close line item processing if stmt
        }   //close hasOwnProperty if stmt
        }   //close datain processing for loop

    var recordId = record.save({
            enableSourcing: true,   //enables sourcing during record update
            ignoreMandatoryFields: false    
        });
    return recordId;

}   //close create invoice function

return {
        'post' : createInvoice
};
}); //close define module declaration
```

I am super new to Netsuite and especially Suitescript 2.0. Could anyone help me figure out what could have gone wrong while converting 1.0 to 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

don't name your variable record

change 'var record = record.create...' to 'var recordObj = record.create...'

avoid using variable names that are the same as SS 2.x modules

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have unclosed  braces in your suitescript 2.0 version,  try this:

```js
// Create a NetSuite invoice
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType Restlet
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

//define and declare modules
define(['N/record'], function ( record) {

    var handler = {};
//function to create a new invoice record with data from API

function createInvoice(datain)
{
    //create record
    var record = record.create({
        type: record.Type.INVOICE,
        isDynamic: false, 
        defaultValues: null
    });

    for (var fieldname in datain)
    {
        if (datain.hasOwnProperty(fieldname))
        {
        if (fieldname!='recordtype' && fieldname!='id')
        {
            var value = datain[fieldname];

            // process non-item fields
            if (value && typeof value != 'object')
            {
                record.setValue({
                fieldId: fieldname,
                value: value
                });
            }   //close non-item field processing if stmt

            // process line item sublist objects
            if (value && typeof value == 'object')
            {
                for (var itemobject in value)
                {
                    record.selectNewLine({sublistId:'item'});   //selects a new line at the end of a sublist
                    var lineitemobject= value[itemobject];
                    for (var lineitemfieldname in lineitemobject)
                    {
                        var lineitemfieldvalue = lineitemobject[lineitemfieldname];
                        record.setCurrentSublistValue({
                            sublistId: 'item',
                            fieldId: lineitemfieldname,
                            value: lineitemfieldvalue
                        });
                    }   //close lineitemobject for loop
                    record.commitLine({sublistId: 'item'});//Commits the currently selected line on a sublist --> dynamic mode only
                }   //close value for loop
            }   //close line item processing if stmt
        }   //close hasOwnProperty if stmt
        }   //close datain processing for loop

    var recordId = record.save({
            enableSourcing: true,   //enables sourcing during record update
            ignoreMandatoryFields: false    
        });
    return recordId;
    }
}
   
handler.post = function (context) {
    try {
        var InvoiceID=createInvoice(context);
   //add your return stuff
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        log.error('Error Creating Invoice', e.message);
            return { 'responseStructure': { 'codeStatus': 'ERROR', 'descriptionStatus': 'blablablbla' }, 'internalId': '' };
    }


});
```